# Magento2 compatibility with PHP7.4

Tags: php, hosting, magento2

the current hosting provider i have is now forcing me to update in the near future to PHP7.4.
At this point i have several Magento2 stores with the following versions: 2.3.1 / 2.3.4 / 2.3.6

Are those versions above compatible with PHP7.4?

If not, what solutions do i have in order to have this situation fixed.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe documentation PHP 7.4 is fully tested with Magento versions above the 2.3.7. It should also work for your Magento versions as well.

You can find Magento 2.3 requirements [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

Comment: Thanks...but all my versions are below 2.3.7, so that is what is worrying me.

Comment: I only have one personal experience with Magento 2.3.3 with PHP 7.4, and i never encounter any compatibility issues. Magento shouldn't have any problem with this php version upgrade.